# Cin is being ignored after one input

Tags: c++, iostream

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    const string FILE_NAME = "StudentData.txt";
    string myData;
    ofstream outfile("StudentData.txt");

    cout << "What is your full name? \n";
    cin >> myData;
    outfile << myData << '\n';

    cout << "Please Enter Street 1 \n";
    cin >> myData;
    outfile << myData << '\n';

    cout << "test";

    return 0;
}
```

In this code, I attempt to get > 1 Variable with cin, but the code seems to skip past the input request and just runs through it.

I've looked and seen that I should use cin.ignore(), but I have no idea how to apply it.

Comment: `std::cin >> myData;` reads input up to the first whitespace. If the input was a first name and last name it would only read the first name; the last name would be read at the **second** input statement. Use [`std::getline`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) to read a **line** of input.